# Conditional HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, basic-authentication

I want to implement HTTP basic authentication on my staging server, but only for those outside the local network. I have a Rails 3.1 app. In application.rb, I have the following:

```
class ApplicationController << ActionController::Base
  http_basic_authenticate_with :realm => "Staging", :name => "user", :password => "password" if :need_authentication?

private

  def need_authentication?
    Rails.env == "staging" && request.remote_addr !~ /^192.168.0.\d{1,3}$/
  end

end
```

Here's the rub: even when the `need_authentication?` method *explicitly* returns `false`, the app *still* asks me to authenticate, as if it's completely ignoring the if clause at the end.

So, is there any way to only require authentication under certain conditions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what worked:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_if_staging

private

  def authenticate_if_staging
    if Rails.env == 'staging' && request.remote_addr !~ /^192.168.0.\d{1,3}$/
      authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic 'Staging' do |name, password|
        name == 'username' && password == 'secret'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

'Staging' is the name of the realm. This is not required, but can be used for clarification.

Answer (score 7):

In Rails 4, the :if condition works. For example,

```
class ApplicationController < ApplicationController::Base
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "user", password: "password" if Rails.env == 'staging'
end
```

or if you want a helper method to set the condition,

```
class ApplicationController < ApplicationController::Base
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "user", password: "password", if: :need_authentication?

  private
  def need_authentication?
    Rails.env == 'staging'
  end
end
```